# how to read whole data from datainputstream by a loop

Tags: java, loops, datainputstream

I've just started to work with data files in java and I don't know how to define loop to read whole file, not only a single line. I'm absolutely not sure am I thinking correctly::

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.dat"));
    String name = null;
    do  {
        name = dis.readUTF();
        System.out.println(name);
    } while (!name.equals(null));
    dis.close();
}
```

When I'm trying this way, it shows me exactly what I want but with this kind of error:

szampon 8.80 120

Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException

zel 9.23 300

pasta 12.99 140
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:345)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:594)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:569)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:13)

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: What if the file is of 80GB?

Comment: Then, there's a problem :D

Comment: You can only use `readUTF()` to read data if it was written with `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()`, was it?

Comment: Yes, it was, and if it's reading a single line it works correctly. But the problem is how to read unknown number of lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help you @Pawel

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.dat"));
StringBuffer inputLine = new StringBuffer();
String tmp;
while ((tmp = dis.readLine()) != null) {
     inputLine.append(tmp);
     System.out.println(tmp);
}
dis.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this change

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.dat"));
String name = null;
do  {
    name = dis.readUTF();
    System.out.println(name);
} while ( dis.available() > 0);
dis.close();
}
```

The readUTF method will not return null , so you need to check if there any bytes available to read.

Comment: Calling `available()` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: You're the boss! Thanks!

Comment: Why is that bad?

Comment: @Paweł there's very rarely a reason to call `available()`, and most people don't understand clearly what it does. In this case it's used as a hack; you could also catch `EOFException` which would be another hack. A more viable approach would be to store the amount of items in a header.

Comment: The documentation for `DataInputStream.available` clearly says that it returns an _estimate_ of the number of bytes available. So there's no guarantee it will return the correct value.